# Select Statement with multiple "and"

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to pull data from a table in access based on the sql query shown below. I continue to get an error under "order"(1,2,3,4,5 etc) because there's multiple "systems" for one location and each system has there own order. Thats why i first select the system then get the order based on what system is selected, however i cant figure out the error.

```
 str = "Select last, first, comments From list Where ((Systems='" + comboBox12.Text +"')And (loc='" + locno + "')And (Order='" + Num1 + "'))";
```

Num1 = double datype and matches the type on access. Any suggestions are appreciate.d

More backgroud, a Loc has multiple Systems, each system has first/last names assigned to each system with first/last having an order of 1 to 10. So 1-10 can be repeated multiple times for the same Loc because theres multiple systems. Iam not sure if the code gets confused when by the order.

Comment: Side note: you should never concatenate your statements because of possible sql injection. Use parameterized queries instead. Concerning your problem: is it not quite clear from your question, but if type of `Order` is numerical - you should not enclose `Num1` into single quotes.

Comment: If you ever mentioning error - post exact exception with details...or at least exception message. Also I agree to @AndyKorneyev [use parameters in your query](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06)

Comment: We can't really solve a problem in your code, if you just post code that assigns a SQL string to some variable, presumably this bit works.

Comment: try store procedure my friend

Comment: As others have stated, there are several things that should be corrected and you have not provided enough detail. That said, I get the feeling that you are trying to use multiple values for the 'Order' criteria. In that case, you need to use an IN clause, not equal operator. [Order] IN(1,2,3,4) instead of Order = '1,2,3,4'.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the fact you should [**really** parameterise that query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to prevent SQL injections, the issue with your statement is the `Order` property. You're confusing SQL because it thinks you mean `ORDER BY`.

Simply rectify this by enclosing it in `[]`:

```
str = "Select last, first, comments From list Where ((Systems='" + comboBox12.Text +"')And (loc='" + locno + "')And ([Order]='" + Num1 + "'))";
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3bc6d/1)

You should really consider not using reserved words for column names though, such as `last`, `first`, `order` and `system`.

Comment: Let us not forget the reserved words.

Comment: @Fionnuala Yep, he has plenty in there (4 in the code he posted!). Added a disclaimer :)